# How can I generate yearly statement table with details on every account on every month in a single report?

Tags: gnucash, annual-report

I want to know if anybody has generated GNUCash custom report with months as columns reporting Income/Expense on every account. For example:
[image: Like shown].

The idea is to show the following in a single report.

1. Opening and Closing balances
2. Income/Expenses every month

Comment: You can get pretty close with a multi-column profit & loss report, one for each month.  It's going to repeat the categories for each month though and you would need to customize for each month as well.

Comment: Hi Andy, Thanks for the reply.  I have been using the reports "Account Summary" and the "Income statements" for the current and previous month to observe the change in the balances and compare the data.  
But as you know its a bit inconvenient to move back and forth between the four reports.
Is it possible to modify the existing scm files to get the required reports?

Comment: One alternative could be to create a budget then use the Budget Report for the monthly income and expenses on every account. Then maybe use a Net Worth Linechart with Table for the monthly opening/closing balance. Would this help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method I have found works and can be found at [Using GnuCash](https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Using_GnuCash)

> As of GnuCash 2.6.15, the Tutorial & Concepts Guide contains a Reports
>   chapter. Please refer to the Guide for details about the reports
>   included with GnuCash.
>
> **A single report that shows summary amounts for multiple months for multiple accounts**
>
> To create a single report that shows summary amounts for multiple
>   months for multiple accounts (for example, monthly totals for expense
>   accounts over the course of a year), you can use the Transaction
>   Report
>
> 1. Choose your Accounts as the Accounts source in the Accounts tab, e.g. highlight "Expenses" and click "Select children"
> 2. Set sortkeys in the Sorting tab: Primary key is Account Name, Primary subtotal is enabled. Secondary key is Date, secondary subtotal
>      for date key is Monthly
> 3. Enable Subtotal table in the Display tab
>
> --Provided by Anthony Dardis

I also recommend In the General Tab, enable Table for Exporting.
This will allow you to copy and paste the multi-column table including totals and the Averages column into a spreadsheet program

This is desirable because there is no way presently to disable the pages long detail lines that display below the table.

[This is an example of one I produced.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ai2Q4.png)

Comment: This perfectly meets my need.. I can see the money flow over a given period of time with the preferred frequency.  Thanks..

Comment: Is it possible to get this to sum the parent accounts too? E.g. if I just want to see aggregates of main categories like income/expense/debt per month?

Answer (score 2):

This older post:
[GnuCash monthly income-expense report](http://gnucash.1415818.n4.nabble.com/Monthly-Income-Expense-Reports-td1561239.html) worked for me.  More specifically, it is the following answer given by "trythis":

"Reports> 
Sample and Custom> 
Custom and multicolumn report> 
Options> Number of Columns, 12> 
select Income Statement under Contents > click [add>>] 12 times 
Click OK or Apply. (this could take some time for it to finish)

Then on the report under each column of data, click Edit Options> 
General> select your date ranges, for each column."

found in the above page that worked for me.

Note that:
1. setting this up the first time is not hard but takes time.  However, once you save the report, you can re-run it at any time.
2. The result has the account names repeated for each month.  However, if you save the report in html format, you can open it in a spreadsheet and, after a bit of formatting, delete unwanted columns. I did not find it hard. (BTW, the "clear direct formatting" feature of LO Calc has been helpful to me).

A colleague who uses QuickBooks, but not GnuCash, asked me to make this report and I was happy when I succeeded.

FYI: I used GnuCash 2.6.19 on Ubuntu 18.04